# Firebase: find child name with specific key value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would you return the name of the child a particular key value is located in?

Using the example in Firebases' docs ...

```
// Assume we have the following data in the Database:
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Ada",
    "last": "Lovelace"
  }
}
```

How would I return "name" only using the key value "Ada" in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't "return" anything.  You query it, and it generates results that match your query.  There's isn't a query that gives you the just the name of some key whose data was matched in some query.  When you do a query or listen at some location, you'll end up with a DataSnapshot that you can examine.  That snapshot will contain the *entire* structure matched by your query.

On top of that, in the case from the docs, "first" isn't even guaranteed to be unique.  There could be many locations that have a first="Ada".  And if you queried for that, you'd get *all* of those records in your query results.  Then it's up to the client to filter through them all to find the right one.

If you want to assume, in that example, first names (like "Ada") are actually unique, and you want to use that to get a minimal snapshot with just the key under which it was stored, you can maintain a reverse map of the first name string back to the string of the key.  You'd have to maintain that mapping in a different location of your database.  So if you assume that "Ada" must actually be a unique child value among a set of data at the same location, you could have another location in the database that maintains this reverse mapping:

```
"first_names": {
    "Ada": "name"
}
```

Then you can simply query the location "/first_names/Ada" that contains the value "name".